# ruby - construct escaped command in code

Tags: ruby, escaping

I have the following command I execute via the windows 10 `command prompt` which works

C:>`someapp.exe -n "conf:conf_abc:\"Acc 0 (ABC=234)\",\"ABC-DEF.GH.IJKL\",\"0\",\"\",\"0\",\"\"" -b input_file.abc  -P vxyz > output_temp.def`

I want to use this in Ruby code as a string `command` and execute it via `system(command)`.

I do the following

```
command = "someapp.exe -n "conf:conf_abc:\"Acc 0 (ABC=234)\",\"ABC-DEF.GH.IJKL\",\"0\",\"\",\"0\",\"\"" -b input_file.abc  -P vxyz > output_temp.def"
system(command)
```

This gives me error `syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting end-of-input`

How do I go about formatting the command that works in command prompt to work within Ruby ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `%q` sigil to prevent a string interpolation:

```
command = %q|someapp.exe -n "conf:conf_abc:\"Acc...|
system(command)
```

Comment: this works !! A follow-up -> how could I achieve using a variable in the `command` string - for example - `file_name = "input_file.abc"
command = %q|someapp.exe -n "conf:conf_abc:\"Acc 0 (ABC=234)\",\"ABC-DEF.GH.IJKL\",\"0\",\"\",\"0\",\"\"" -b #{file_name}  -P vxyz > output_temp.def|
`  - this won't work as the string interpolation is off.

Comment: Use e. g. [`String#%`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-25): `command = %q|foo %s|; command = command % file_name`.

Comment: Or use the multi-argument form of [`system`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Kernel.html#method-i-system) and bypass the quoting problems altogether.